# AWS Sagemaker, how to connect existing local jupyter notebook with ML algorithms to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-sagemaker

I have written a code for ML in my local machine in jupyter notebook. I notice that AWS Sagemaker has its own notebook instances too. '

1. Can I upload my existing local jupyter notebook in AWS Sagemaker directly?
   or
2. Do I need to type the entire code again in instance of AWS Sagemaker jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Can I upload my existing local jupyter notebook in AWS Sagemaker directly? or
   Yes you can upload from local disk or computer
2. Do I need to type the entire code again in instance of AWS Sagemaker jupyter notebook?
   No